# How to override the django save method to run a stored procedure to save an object

Tags: python, django-admin, custom-action

I am a newbie in Django and developing a CRUD Operations app on our legacy Oracle DB. One of my requirement is that after users fills up a Admin add form and clicks on Submit, instead off calling the save method it should call the stored procedure for all the validations and storing the data. Normal Add and and Save works like a charm. So is this possible?